# Why CPU cost so many time executes getNextJarEntry method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, jvm, disk

one of my servers's http response is very slow, it average costs 20000ms-30000ms when the response return. but another servers only cost hundreds of millisecond. the application's source code is the same.

I use `visualvm` trying to find out the reason, and I find that the method `java.util.jar.JarInputStream.getNextJarEntry()` cost 99% time during the proceduce:

[image: time cost]

Why this situation happens, or How can I find more details about this situatiion?

Comment: Well, it looks like some dynamic class loading stuff, perhaps some reflection? Does your code contain something like that? Actually, in the web application I am working on, the initialization of the Hibernate entity manager takes a very long time on a Windows machine (much quicker on Linux), due to different class-loading mechanism (and **a lot** of ORM classes). Luckily, it happens only on the web-app startup, not on every request. But it might point you to the cause of your problem.

Comment: In this profile, that method is encapsulating the actual work with the jar file, in the worst case, skimming over the entire file. Jar indexing might help, so do shared class data archives or optimized module image, but all of them would depend on the class loader support, as this is not the standard class loader.